# Why Install4j requires reboot on next installation after uninstall?

Tags: install4j

I have two windows installers built using install4j I do the following steps:

1. Install version X
2. Uninstall version X
3. Install version x + 1

The result is the following message: ***The installation/removal of a previous program was not completed. You will need to restart your computer to complete that installation.***

 I know that the reason is for this message is the uninstall step adding the registry key ***HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\RebootCheckFile*** 

 The question is why the uninstall step adds this registry key?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the reason is that a file could not be deleted because it was still in use by a running executable.

While the uninstaller is still open at the end, search for the log file in the %TEMP% directory (a file whose name starts with "i4jlog") and check the output of the "UninstallFilesAction".

---

Alternatively, the installer may not have been able to overwrite a file because it was in use. Check the log files of the installer for any occurrences of "Delayed installation".

You can suppress reboot by passing the VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.suppressReboot=true
```

to the installer. You can set it as a fixed VM parameter in the "VM arguments" property of the installer.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the log and found some lines like the following: postponing deletion of C:\Program Files\Myserver\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar, but when I looked in the file system couldn't find any of them (like they were actually deleted). Any idea what cause it to do "postponing deletion" and if they were deleted why reboot is still required?

Comment: I would start by checking with procexp which executables still have a lock on "i4jruntime.jar": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: I Tried to check using procexp...It seems the only process is uninstall.exe (generated by install4j). In addition we have Finish screen at the end of the uninstall process. I noticed that the requirement of reboot behavior depends on how fast I close this screen. The faster I do it the more chance it will require reboot (on silent mode it always require restart). This make me think that this is some kind of race condition